# Android automatic horizontally scrolling TextView

Tags: android, scroll, textview

I am trying to implement a single-line text view that will scroll automatically. But I unfortunatly cannot get it to work. The AutoScrollTextView is declared inside a LinearLayout (width and height = fill_parent). The class basically uses a Handler that calls itself to scroll by a given amount. I have simplified the code to only show a text view that should be scrolling by 5 pixels every second.

The log output is correct, the getScrollX() method returns the appropriate scrollX position.

If I don't call `requestLayout()`, nothing gets drawn. `invalidate()` has no effect.

Would anybody have a clue?

```
public class AutoScrollTextView extends TextView {

    public AutoScrollTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        setSingleLine();
        setEllipsize(null);
        setText("Single-line text view that scrolls automatically if the text is too long to fit in the widget");
    }

    // begin to scroll the text from the original position
    public void startScrolling() {
        scrollHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
    }

    private Handler scrollHandler = new Handler() {
        private static final int REFRESH_INTERVAL = 1000;

        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            scrollBy(5, 0);
            requestLayout();
            Log.debug("Scrolled to " + getScrollX() + " px");
            sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, REFRESH_INTERVAL);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Typically for text to scroll , it should be in focus. Have you tried giving focus to your layout ? or say setSelected() to the view?

Comment: Yep, tried to do it from the activity and from the Handler within the custom widget.

Answer (score 248, accepted):

If you don't need to sub-class the `TextView`, you can try this in your layout file:

```
    <TextView
        android:text="Single-line text view that scrolls automatically if the text is too long to fit in the widget" 
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit ="marquee_forever"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true" 
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Also, in your code use the following:

```
findViewById(R.id.serviceColorCode).setSelected(true);
```

[Answer edited based on comments]

Comment: Hi, this works. However I'd love to understand why my custom widget does not work (I'd like to do some other scrolling movement than just right to left)

Comment: Is there any possible way to make this marquee line go back (reverse) when it finish one loop?

Comment: Is it possible to increase the speed of the scrolling?

Comment: I found if the TextView occupied whole width of layout, then the text will auto scroll perfectly. But if it didn't take whole width of layout, sometime it will not scroll its text...

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using singleLine="true", since that has been deprecated?

Comment: the TextView have to be set selected: textView.setSelected(true);

Comment: Wow it won't work at all for me unless setSelected is set. Thanks!

Comment: the whole text should be seen while scrolling through. the end text is dotted (too......) . so there is no point of scrolling. please suggest solution.

Comment: Please note it should be `maxLines="1"` as `singleLine` was deprecated

Comment: You must use singleLine attribute in order to make it work. Tried with maxLines only, on AppCompatTextView, nothing. So singleLine and setSelected(..) are the key.

Comment: Doesn't work on my Samsung Note 8 running Android 6.0.1

Comment: Doesn't work on my Samsung Note 8 running Android 6.0.1 until I added singleLine = true (thanks, @bengous).

Comment: For me it works with `singleLine` (not `maxLines`) and without `setSelected`. This is the wonderful world of Android UI development.

Comment: hi. it doesn't work for me. It only displays ellipsis at the end of the textview but it does not scroll.

Comment: For some devices I found out it does not work unless you add the deprecated "singleLine=true" along with the "maxLines=1". And "setSelected(true)" was still needed. Cheers!

Comment: Where does the id come from? This code doesn't work. -1

Comment: How do I do the same, but vertically scrolling?

Comment: It showed me the scrollbar for a moment and then it was deleted.
I changed the scrollbars value in **xml**  to `"none"`

Comment: linter warn about maxLines with message: "Combining ellipsize=marquee and maxLines=1 can lead to crashes. Use singleLine=true instead."

Answer (score 25):

After these xml code as answered by @rajat

```
<TextView
        android:text="Single-line text view that scrolls automatically if the text is too long to fit in the widget" 
        android:singleLine="true" 
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit ="marquee_forever"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true" 
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

We need to set

```
TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview1);
  tv.setSelected(true);
```

which finally made mine work

Comment: the whole text should be seen while scrolling through. the end text is dotted (too......) . so there is no point of scrolling. please suggest solution.

Comment: I think you might have set android:ellipsize="end". Check once. Let me know if its not the case. Also if possible please share your code here

Comment: no i have "marquee" . but i am doing this inside an recyclerview. the outer recyclerview has a element that contains the textview. then the text view has a long text. i want to show it in one line . and this will scroll automatically for infinity.

Comment: Ok. Not sure why using it is recycler view will disable the auto scroll.

Answer (score 18):

My solution works:

```
<TextView
     android:id="@+id/titolotxt"
     android:layout_width="..."
     android:layout_height="..."
     android:ellipsize="marquee"
     android:gravity="left"
     android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
     android:singleLine="true"
     android:text="@string/titolo"/>
```

And the `TextView` have to be setted selected: 
`textView.setSelected(true);` by code in `onCreate` for example.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Your Text should be big in length otherwise it won't work for small-length text if it does not exceed your screen size.

```
<  TextView
        android:id="@+id/support"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=" enter the large text that wont fit on screen "
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        />
```

and in your activity

```
 TextView textView=findViewById(R.id.support);
        textView.setSelected(true);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
// this TextView will marquee because it is selected
TextView marqueeText1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.marquee_text_1);
marqueeText1.setSelected(true);

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/marquee_text_1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true" />
```

Answer (score 3):

In order to move text, besides adding attributes:

```
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:singleLine="true"
android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
android:focusable="true"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:scrollHorizontally="true"
```

it is **necessary for View to be in focus**, so this can be done in two ways:

1. Programmatically:

   ```
   tv.setSelected (true);
   ```
2. Do everything in XML by adding ***requestFocus*** tag:

   ```
   <TextView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true">
        <requestFocus />
   </TextView>
   ```

Comment: Thanks. I wondered why all the solutions in the other answers didn't work by me.
Because of the absence of the instruction `android:clickable="true"`

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that worked for my case was using scrollview and setting the scroll programatically

Text View inside fragment

```
<HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/hsv_fragment_drafting_now_header_info"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:scrollbars="none">

        <TextView
               android:id="@+id/tv_fragment_drafting_now_header_info"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:fontFamily="@font/circular_std_book"
               android:maxLines="1"
               android:text="A very long text that will be reaching out the screen or view container"
               android:textSize="16sp" />

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Animation, sliding_text.xml

```
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:duration="8000"
      android:fromXDelta="100%"
      android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
      android:repeatCount="infinite"
      android:repeatMode="restart"
      android:toXDelta="-100%" />
```

Block manual scroll and start animation

```
headerInfoScroll.setOnTouchListener(object : View.OnTouchListener{
    override fun onTouch(p0: View?, p1: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
         return true
    }
})

headerInfo.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this.context, R.anim.sliding_text))
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes invalidate wont work until you call invalidate in main thread like follows:

```
handler.post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            yourView.invalidate();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

**setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod())** with **setHorizontallyScrolling(true)** work in my case.

in .java:

```
tv = findViewById(R.id.textViewID);
tv.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
tv.setHorizontallyScrolling(true);
```