# Android: how to truncate TextView in TableLayout?

Tags: android

I have a TextView in a column of my TableLayout.  I would like the TextView to truncate and ellipsize if its text is longer than the column can accommodate, but it just stretches the column and destroys my layout.  None of the suggestions for TextView truncating I have found have worked, I'm assuming this is due to the Table.  Any suggestions?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </TextView>
    <RelativeLayout  
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/Icon"
            android:src="@drawable/icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </ImageView>
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/Value"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/Icon"
            android:text="very long stringvery long stringvery long stringvery long stringvery long stringvery long stringvery long stringvery long stringvery long stringvery long stringvery long stringvery long stringvery long stringvery long stringvery long stringvery long string"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </TextView>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

*EDIT: Code for the table:

```
int fiveDip = convToDip(5, getContext());

Table table = new TableLayout(getContext());
table.setPadding(fiveDip, fiveDip, fiveDip, fiveDip);
table .setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
```

Comment: Could you provide your TableLayout xml?

Comment: @Joe. I define it in code, I added the code as an edit to my question.

Answer (score 13):

You need to set **both** [`shrinkColumns`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html#attr_android:shrinkColumns) and [`stretchColumns`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html#attr_android:stretchColumns) on the column containing the TextView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:shrinkColumns="1"
    android:stretchColumns="1">     
        <TableRow>
            <View 
                android:background="#f00"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="40dp" />

            <TextView 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="Example text that is very loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong" />

            <View 
                android:background="#00f"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="40dp" />
        </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: This is where I went wrong too, you have to tell it which column indexes should shrink and grow.

Answer (score 0):

Your xml and code seems unrelated to the problem you've stated. Nevertheless, have you tried doing `android:singleLine="true"` for your TextView. For Marquee, see [Android automatic horizontally scrolling TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472362/android-automatic-horizontally-scrolling-textview/5472637#5472637)

Also, you can wrap your `TableLayout` with a `ScrollView` to enable scrolling.

Comment: I tried with just adding singleLine="true", and then by using your code for marquee.  Neither worked.   A would prefer to truncate, than to wrap with a scrollview.