# Scroll text in a horizontal scroll view

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-scrollview

I have seen a few posts similar to my issue. However, the solutions mentioned in those posts did not help me fix the problem. Here is the scenario. I have a TextView in a horizontal scroll view. The idea is as soon as a text (larger than the view) is appended to the TextView, it must be automatically scrolled to end. Here is the layout snippet.

```
<HorizontalScrollView
             android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_margin="5dp"
             android:background="@color/subTitleColor"
             android:fillViewport="true"
             android:scrollbars="none" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/drillPath"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:text="this is a such a long text that scrolling is needed, scroll more"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="@color/textColorWhite" />

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Upon an event, I do the following.

```
textView.append("do auto scroll");
```

Effectively, it should scroll the text to the end. But it isn't! What is it I am lacking?

Comment: never tried it, but see if setting gravity=right works, either in TextView or HorizontalScrollView

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, your scrollview will never scroll since its content view (the TextView) is in `fill_parent` mode. it should wrap its content in order  to leave space for the text and be bigger than its parent. (change your textView width to : `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` )

Then, there is nothing here to request the scroll, I don't think it should happen automatically.

Add something like this to request the scroll to the end of your scroll view :

```
   textView.append("do auto scroll");

    scrollView.post(new Runnable() {            
        @Override
        public void run() {
               scrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_RIGHT);              
        }
    });
```

Let me know when you've tried it.

Comment: Thanks! It worked! Just a quickie. Can we make the scrollview do the scrolling from the layout XML?

Comment: I don't think so...  :/

Answer (score 0):

Let try to fix your TextView height and change this width layoutParam to wrap_content

```
<HorizontalScrollView
             android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"     <-- Here
             android:layout_height="10dp"            <-- Here
             android:layout_margin="5dp"
             android:background="@color/subTitleColor"
             android:fillViewport="true"
             android:scrollbars="none" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/drillPath"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"  <-- Here
                android:layout_height="10dp"         <-- Here
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:text="this is a such a long text that scrolling is needed, scroll more"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="@color/textColorWhite" />

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Because of this layoutParam, Your text do not have enough size to scroll. It only have max width is screen width.

Hope that help.

Comment: Unless I misunderstood, It has nothing to do with the TextView's height, why do you change it to 10dp ? However, you're right about the width.

Comment: It's an example to present my mind that mr.Renjith need to fix the android:layout_height. If you do not fix the android:layout_height size, the TextView will grow the height, not the width.

Comment: Nothing will make the height change since its a single line TextView. I would agree if 'android:SingleLine' would be set to false.