# Android ListView ItemClickListener not working properly with HorizontalScrollView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-dialog

my OnItemClickListener does not work properly. I have a custom Dialog Layout with a ListView. The ListView holds TextViews as Item. The TextView should be scrollable so I put my TextView in a HorizontalScrollView because my text can get long.

But the problem now is, that the OnItemClickListener does not getting called, only when I remove my ScrollView.

This is my ListView Item XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <HorizontalScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            />
    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:background="#000"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And here is how I set the On Item click Listener:

```
ListView listView = builder.findViewById(R.id.listviewDialog);
        listView.setClickable(true);

        ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(ContextActivity, R.layout.list_item2, R.id.tv, aListe);

        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                //
            }
        });
```

It works when I add the following attribute to the top most layout of my Item XML:

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

But then my click events fire only when I don't click on the text.

Can anyone help me?

EDIT:

Solution posted here from W0rmH0le. Basically, I need EditText, not TextView:
[Horizontal scroll on textview on android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14097440/horizontal-scroll-on-textview-on-android/14098053)

EDIT2:
On Item Click still broken even with focusable false etc. checkbox works but TextView and EditText don’t. 
So now my EditText gets the click listener, not the listView

Answer (score 0):

use `android:scrollHorizontally="true"` and EditText instead of TextView

try something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"/
            android:scrollHorizontally="true">
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:background="#000"/>
</LinearLayout >
```

Comment: Ok with your solution I have to remove my View because HorizontalScrollView can host only one direct child. But even if I remove my view, my onItemClick event still dont getting called, even when I add  android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"

Comment: you need to remove `HorizontalScrollView` and to add to your EditText`android:scrollHorizontally="true"`

Comment: I can't scroll horizontally in TextView without HorizontalScrollView. Please see my Edit. With EditText I can scroll without HorizontalScrollView

Comment: that's what I mean, I have to use EditText but my OnClickListener still doesn't get called. I need somehow to pass the click event trough the EditText

Comment: Okay, that's because I set android:focusable="false" for my EditText. But I need that because otherwise, the EditText gets the focus to edit the text inside of it.