# How to animate the textview (very very long text )scroll automatically horizontally

Tags: android, textview

I am not interested in Marquee because, in Marquee you can not control the speed of marquee.
I have tried to animate the textview but Parent view clips the text at the end even though all parent layout and view groups encompassing textviews are set with two flags clipchildren= false, clipToPadding=false.

Am I missing something or is there a better work around ?

The xml looks like

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="66dp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="#585858"
        android:textSize="32sp" >
    </TextView>
```

and code snippet look like

```
TextView textView2 = (TextView)findViewById( R.id.textview1 );    
textView2.startAnimation((Animation)AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.translate));
```

Comment: please tell me ur problem was solved.if it is solved please tell the procedure or post some code.

Answer (score 8):

I am sure this will definitely solve the problem of the large audience out there.

Q: Auto-scroll a single line long text message(either using hard_coding or from string.xml) horizontally & infinitely at a reasonable speed but using marquee(try it once at least). No clipping

Step 1:
In activity_main.xml file:

```
<TextView
    android:text="either hard coding or from string.xml"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"  
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_light" />
```

Step 2: In main_activity java file 
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    textView.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
    textView.setSelected(true);
    textView.setSingleLine(true);
    textView.setText("Oxfam says 8 men as rich as half the world. | Govt may set threshold for probe into deposits. | At least 32 dead after Turkish plane hits village.");}}
```

//one can remove the last line  line if he has already feed the long input

Answer (score 7):

I think you can use translate animation. Something like this

```
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="5000"
    android:fromXDelta="100"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:repeatMode="restart"
    android:toXDelta="-100" />
```

And add to your textview like this

```
textview.startAnimation((Animation)AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(Context,R.anim.scroll_animation));
```

Hope it can help you.

Comment: I have done precisely this, but parent view still clips the text

Comment: OK, I think it's time for you to post some code. Could you please ?

Answer (score 5):

Just add this to your textview

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="Your_Text" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Here was my **SOLUTION**

To make the long text inside textview not be cut by parent view or by screen, I have done two things.

First, let textview inside a scroolview like below code

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/marquee_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="30sp"/>
</ScrollView>
```

Then, I measure my text size then refine the textview param by doing this.

```
    marqueeText.setText("my long text");
    Paint textPaint = marqueeText.getPaint();
    String text = marqueeText.getText().toString();//get text
    int width = Math.round(textPaint.measureText(text));//measure the text size
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params =  marqueeText.getLayoutParams();
    params.width = width;
    marqueeText.setLayoutParams(params); //refine

    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRealMetrics(displaymetrics);
    int screenWidth = displaymetrics.widthPixels;

    //this is optional. do not scroll if text is shorter than screen width
    //remove this won't effect the scroll
    if (width <= screenWidth) {
        //All text can fit in screen.
        return;
    }
    //set the animation
    TranslateAnimation slide = new TranslateAnimation(0, -width, 0, 0);
    slide.setDuration(20000);
    slide.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    slide.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);
    slide.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    marqueeText.startAnimation(slide);
```

I hope this solution which took me half a day to research can help others who might meet the same problem like me.

Comment: It's not work for me, the text slide and animated but with cut of text, Can someone help?!

Comment: @AmalKronz Try to debug your width used by marqueeText if the text was cut. Also, you can use the tool hierarchy view to view your elements to make sure not other views are overlapping the marqueeText. Good luck

Comment: but it restarts animation everytime, when animation ends. I want to scroll text from right to left without starting from fast.

Answer (score 2):

Can try out this. This is a solution using TranslateAnimation for creating an auto scrolling text (horizontal scroll, from Right to Left)  (Tested on Android 8)

### Class: AnimationAutoTextScroller.java

```
/**
 * A Class for automatically scrolling text horizontally from Right to Left 
 * using TranslateAnimation so that the scrolling speed can be controlled -Suresh Kodoor
 */

public class AnimationAutoTextScroller {

    Animation animator;
    TextView  scrollingTextView;
    int       duration = 50000;  // default value

    public AnimationAutoTextScroller(TextView tv, float screenwidth) {

        this.scrollingTextView = tv;
        this.animator = new TranslateAnimation(
                Animation.ABSOLUTE, screenwidth,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, -1f,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0f,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0f
        );
        this.animator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        this.animator.setDuration(this.duration);
        this.animator.setFillAfter(true);
        this.animator.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);
        this.animator.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);

        // setAnimationListener();
    }

    public void setDuration(int duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    public void setScrollingText(String text) {
        this.scrollingTextView.setText(text);
    }

    public void start() {
        this.scrollingTextView.setSelected(true);
        this.scrollingTextView.startAnimation(this.animator);
    }

    public void setAnimationListener() {

        animator.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            }
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                // This callback function can be used to perform any task at the end of the Animation
            }
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            }
        });
    }
}
```

### Layout XML:  (keep the TextView under a HorizontalScrollView)

```
 <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/hguide3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/vguide2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/vguide1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/hguide2">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/translateanimatortextviewscroller"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:text=""
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:background="#000000ff"
        android:textColor="#ff0000"
        android:textSize="55dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans" />

      </HorizontalScrollView>
```

### Activity:

```
TextView scrollertextview = findViewById(R.id.translateanimatortextviewscroller);
textscroller = new AnimationAutoTextScroller(scrollertextview, screenwidth);
textscroller.setScrollingText(scrollertext);
textscroller.setDuration(60000);
textscroller.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

**Add this Animation file:**

```
<translate
    android:duration="7000"
    android:fromYDelta="0%p"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:repeatCount="10"
    android:repeatMode="restart"
    android:toYDelta="-100%p" />
```

```
/*Put your text view inside scroll*/
        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/dp_size_220"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_size_16"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/iv_myra_notification"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/iv_one_way"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/marquee_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="@{itemData.notification.message}"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                tools:text="bfnfkjnvlen jknjkgnojeng"/>
        </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code it will help you out Shri n HERO

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate>
    <translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="5000"
    android:fromXDelta="1500"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:repeatMode="restart"
    android:toXDelta="-1250" />

</translate>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me.
Place your textview inside a scroll view and then perform **TranslateAnimation** on the scrollview's child, my case its the LinearLayout.
I am actually adding multiple views dynamically inside this linear layout.

```
<ScrollView android:id="@+id/textScrollView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/textLayout"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

TranslateAnimation slide = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, height, -textLayout.getHeight());
    slide.setDuration(movementSpeed);
    slide.setRepeatCount(-1);
    slide.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);
    slide.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());

textLayout.startAnimation(slide);

height --> The point start scrolling up (in my case device height (device bottom))
movementSpeed --> scrolling speed
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this simple way with **ellipsize** and **marquee** options using [@rajath answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472362/android-automatic-horizontally-scrolling-textview)

```
<TextView
    android:text="Single-line text view that scrolls automatically if the text is too long to fit in the widget" 
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit ="marquee_forever"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" 
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its really frustrating,...
But the answer is simple,
Use Edittext instead of TextView, and wrap it in horizontalscrollview
At the same time, setfocusable: false

```
   <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:scrollbars="none">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/post_message"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:outlineAmbientShadowColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:shadowColor="#000000"
            android:shadowDx="1.5"
            android:shadowDy="1.3"
            android:shadowRadius="1.6"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="20dp" />
    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Thanks to Hein, add the animation code

```
final EditText textView =  view.findViewById(R.id.post_message);
        textView.startAnimation((Animation) AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,R.anim.horizontal_animation));
        String message="LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLong Text.";
        textView.setText(message);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<translate>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:duration="5000"
android:fromXDelta="1500"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
android:repeatCount="infinite"
android:repeatMode="restart"
android:toXDelta="-1250" />
```

Comment: this code is used to move text from right to left like (marque in php )  @arghtype