# How to animate TextView with progressbar

Tags: java, android, progress-bar

I have a `TextView` on top of `ProgressBar`. When `ProgressBar` changes then the position of the TextView have to change on top of progression. How can I create such a solution?

**Output :**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Follow this**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rl"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="#d6e6de"
    >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Create ProgressBar"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_start"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Start Operation"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btn"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/btn_start"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Refer this below examples..

https://android--code.blogspot.in/2015/08/android-create-progressbar.html

and

[How to animate the textview (very very long text )scroll automatically horizontally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18826870/how-to-animate-the-textview-very-very-long-text-scroll-automatically-horizonta)

Comment: Thanks for your response. But what I need is to animate TextView position related to the progression. Hope you realize.

Comment: I am attaching the reference image take a look.

Comment: @AfinasEM sry for the late response..please check my updated answer

Comment: I need the TextView also animated horizontally.

Comment: check my updated answer....please try to customise the code try to achieve what you want....

Answer (score 0):

Try using progressBar getProgress method and then change the text with setText method!

```
int state = progressBar.getProgress();
textView.setText(state);
```

Comment: Please check the question. I want the code to animate Textview. not for updating value. Thank you.