# Animate textView inside the cardView to display long texts

Tags: android, xml

I am to animate the textView which might have long text inside a CardView. I found couple of answers from this question [animate textView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18826870/how-to-animate-the-textview-very-very-long-text-scroll-automatically-horizonta).

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
android:id="@+id/lineCard"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="120dp"
android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/Black">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvCallerName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:backgroundTint="#00FFFFFF"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/White"
        android:textSize="32sp"/>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

I am using `ellipsize,marqueeRepeatLimit,scrollHorizontally,singleLine`. But still it doesnt work. The text is displayed in two lines. What am I missinh here ? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
 android:id="@+id/lineCard"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="120dp"
android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/Black">
 <LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvCallerName"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:backgroundTint="#00FFFFFF"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@color/White"
    android:textSize="32sp"/>
   </LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Added linear layout and then put textview inside that

Comment: To be fair, I tried in a textView which isnt inside a cardView. It works fine. But inside a cardView doesnt work properly though

Comment: I can't get  your comment can you explain clearly what you exactly need ...

Comment: If I apply your solution to textView which is not inside a `cardView`, it is working. But inside a cardView, still doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

First, create the animation in XML.

```
 <translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="5000"
    android:fromXDelta="100"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:repeatMode="restart"
    android:toXDelta="-100" />
```

then add animation

```
textview.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.scroll_animation));
```

For Simple animation, you can use

```
<TextView
                android:id="@+id/attatchFilename"
                android:layout_width="170dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/chooseFile"
                android:layout_below="@id/txtMsg"
                android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text=""
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
                android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever" />
```

Check out this blog as well :
[https://www.journaldev.com/9481/android-animation-example][1]