# Android Google Maps InfoWindow scroll displayed text automatically

Tags: android, google-maps, textview, xamarin.android, google-maps-markers

I would like to display long texts in InfoWindow and I thought it would be great if the text scrolled automatically. I have tried with marquee, but the text is not scrolling. Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Here is my layout code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/infoWindowMaxWidth"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:lines="1"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

My InfoWindowAdapter:

```
class CustomInfoWindowAdapter : Java.Lang.Object, GoogleMap.IInfoWindowAdapter
    {
       .
       .
       .

        private void Render(Marker marker, View view)
        {
            var textView = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.title);
            textView.Text = marker.Title;
            textView.Selected = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: marques is not for scrolling ..  Marque works when the text match the width of the textview

Comment: @TerrilThomas http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472362/android-automatic-horizontally-scrolling-textview

Comment: does your text fill the full textview??

Comment: No, the width is 100dp, and the text is wider than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the info window is not a live view so you will not be able to do what you want to do

Comment: nothing easy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14123243/google-maps-api-v2-custom-infowindow-like-in-original-android-google-maps/15040761#15040761

Comment: @Roosevelt The link tyczj provided doesn't solve animating issues. This is actually "easier" if you hack it to refresh info window periodically with some increasing negative margins.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions! I will definitely try to make it work :)