# How to put the text of a TextView in motion, on android?

Tags: android, layout, imageview, textview

I have a launcher application for each item, I display an `ImageView` with `TextView`, my problem is with applications that have a very long name.

I use one line to display the text so I would have a part and all the title is not displayed but what i want is to display the text that rotates and allows the user to read all the title. So how to put the text in motion.

I saw this technique on a Samsung smartphone. my items are given by the code below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:paddingTop="4dp"
    android:textSize="14dip"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical" />
```

Comment: use android:ellipsize="marquee"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472362/android-automatic-horizontally-scrolling-textview. Check this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
android:singleLine="true"
android:ellipsize="marquee"
```

Alternatively,

```
android:ellipsize="4"// 4 is the integer equivalent for marquee
```

or

```
textView.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use marquee for that:

Use

```
android:ellipsize="marquee"
```

instead of

```
android:ellipsize="end"
```

And [repeat limit](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setMarqueeRepeatLimit%28int%29) as per your requirement.

Hoe this helps.