# Android textview scrollable horizontal

Tags: android

I want to scroll text but It doesn't scroll and  I used this code but it doesn't work. I tried other codes but still not working

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Some text "
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

and this in Adapter class

```
if (tv.getText().toString().length() > tv.getMaxLines()) 
            tv.setSelected(true);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android automatic horizontally scrolling TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472362/android-automatic-horizontally-scrolling-textview)

Comment: Yes I saw it but hopefully it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try this, hope it may helps you.

```
<HorizontalScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:text="Horizontal scroll view will work now"/>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```